# Set element attribute by submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is it possible, when i click on submit on a form to set this a href class to active?

```
<li><a class="" href="#" onClick="goto('#ajanlok', this); return false">Ajánl Dalt!</a></li>
```

Comment: Please post more html source code from your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

- Add on your open form tag the attribute 'onSubmit'.
- Add on your specific a tag the attributes 'id' and 'class'. You can also add the style instead of class attribute.
- Write a javascript method that looks for this a tag i.e. with `getElementById()` or `getElementsByTagname("a")[0]` (in case there is only one a tag in your form or on your site).
- After that add the specific css class name or appropiate style attributes to your a tag.
- Make sure that this function contains a `return true;` at the end of function body.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function like this.

```
function makeActive() {
    document.getElementById("InsertIdOfHref").className += ' active';
}
```

Then just add  `onClick="makeActive();"` and set a deafult class to your `<a>`. like class="AMAGAD"

Next time, Just google it :)

Did some edits. Thanks for the comments

Comment: The element already has an href attribute, so you can't give it a second one, you have to modify the existing one.

Comment: You don't do anything with the result of your string concatenation, so this effectively does nothing. You might have meant `+=`

Comment: The class attribute takes a space separated list of classes, although this particular one doesn't start with any, but a more general solution would add a space before the class name. A better solution would also test the class attribute to make sure that the class wasn't already applied.

Comment: The question says "when i click on submit on a form" so "put this in your href" makes little sense, since submit buttons don't have href attributes. It doesn't make much sense in general either since you would add the extra element to an `<a>` tag not an `href` attribute.

Comment: Btw, if the specific a tag hadn't got the 'class' attribute, that won't work either, even though your way is correct.